# Recursive generic function with type passed as a parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, deserialization

I want to have a recursive generic function, but I cannot use type passed as an argument in generic function invocation, cause of

```
'memberType' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

Is there a way to pass `memberType` to generic method invocation?

Example:

```
class Packet {
  header: Header
  body: Body

  static MEMBERS = [
    ['header', Header, 0,  6],
    ['body',   Body,   6, 10],
  ]
}

class Header {
  size: number
  ttl: number

  static MEMBERS = [
      ['size', 'number',   0,  2],
      ['ttl',  'number',   2,  3],
  ]
}

class Body {
  raw: string

  static MEMBERS = [
      ['raw', 'string',   0,  10]
  ]
}




class Deserializer {
  static Deserialize<T>(serialized: string, type: { new(): T ;}): T {
      const obj = new type();

      const members = obj.constructor['MEMBERS'];

      for(const member of members) {
          var [memberName, memberType, startOffset, len] = member;
          const serializedMember = serialized.substr(startOffset, len) // cut string holding serialized member (like 'qwertyuiop' from example)

          if(memberType == 'number') { // handle primitive type differently
            obj[memberName] = parseInt(serializedMember); 
          } else if(memberType == 'string') { // handle primitive type differently
            obj[memberName] = serializedMember

          } else { // handle non primitives, like Header and Body

// *** issue is on the following line ***
            obj[memberName] = Deserialize<memberType>() // 'memberType' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
          }

      }

      return obj as T;
  }
}

//                  HEADRBOOOOOOODY - description of `serialized` string below
//                  SSTTL (where SS = header.size, TTL = header.ttl)  
const serialized = '11222qwertyuiop'
const packet: Packet = Deserializer.Deserialize<Packet>(serialized, Packet)

// expected `packet` object structure after running `Deserialize`
// Packet
//   * header -> Header
//                 * size -> 11
//                 * ttl  -> 222
//   * body -> Body
//               * raw -> BOOOOOOODY
```

Comment: There's a lot of stuff going on here that causes errors if I drop it into my IDE, but your fundamental issue is that you need to call not `Deserialize<memberType>()` but `Deserializer.Deserialize(serializedMember, memberType)`. Whether or not that works without type assertions is another story.

Answer (score 0):

Right, `memberType` is a value, not a type.  You could get its type from the compiler as `typeof memberType`, but in your case the recursive call to `Deserialize` needs arguments, from which the generic type parameter can be inferred as `typeof memberType` if you pass it in:

```
obj[memberName] = Deserializer.Deserialize(serializedMember, memberType);
```

That should clear up the problem you asked about, but the example code has a lot of type errors and implicit `any` issues which you should probably address.

---

One way to address them is via slight refactoring and the judicious use of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to deal with the places that the compiler can't verify as safe (e.g. `obj[memberName] = parseInt(...)` won't work without an assertion because the compiler won't realize that the property at `memberName` should be a `number`, since it's a higher order inference it can't perform).  Maybe something like:

```
type DeserializableClass<T> = {
  new(): T,
  MEMBERS: readonly {
    [K in keyof T]: readonly [K, string | DeserializableClass<T[K]>, number, number]
  }[keyof T][]
}

class Deserializer {
  static Deserialize<T>(serialized: string, type: DeserializableClass<T>): T {
    const obj = new type();

    const members = type.MEMBERS;

    for (const member of members) {
      var [memberName, memberType, startOffset, len] = member;
      const serializedMember = serialized.substr(startOffset, len) // cut string holding serialized member (like 'qwertyuiop' from example)

      if (typeof memberType !== "string") {
        obj[memberName] = Deserializer.Deserialize(serializedMember, memberType);
      } else if (memberType == 'number') { // handle primitive type differently
        obj[memberName] = parseInt(serializedMember) as any as T[keyof T];
      } else if (memberType == 'string') { // handle primitive type differently
        obj[memberName] = serializedMember as any as T[keyof T];
      }

    }
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Here we've described more exactly what kind of class can be deserialized: it has to have a `MEMBERS` property with the right sort of array of tuples.  Note that this isn't perfectly type safe because `T[keyof T]` is too wide, and you can keep changing things to be safer, but at that point I'd be inclined to make your `MEMBERS` property hold deserializers for primitives also and give up on the strings.  Note how the compiler sees the recursive `Deserialize` call as acceptable, but it still needs to be told that the `string` and `number` cases work.

Also, in order for this to accept `Packet` you need to ensure that your `MEMBERS` static properties are sufficiently literal (tuples tend to get widened to arrays); an easy way to do that is with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), like:

```
static MEMBERS = [
  ['size', 'number', 0, 2],
  ['ttl', 'number', 2, 3],
] as const
```

---

Anyway I won't go farther into the refactoring than this for now.  Hope this helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEASCmYAm8BO0DeAoa0IEsAveALmgDsBXAWwCM0doAXJkMquhxiJsJ-YNACyAUSEAhEQCUAytAC80ANqNcSgOQFi6gDTR1Heql3QADHoBMAXR2rl6liBMGaRkxb0BmG4yvRI0MAA9uQ8WAC+0FhYoJAw4kFIAJ6YjKhgAO5kPKj45ADm0bg8fALCYpKyCsp2GukZzjl5+Sbm0ACMpla+-jDBoUwR0bFQ0AAKYMAA1vBMqbgAFogoqGQIyAy4tIlJZAnJRXi8-IKiEtJyiiq4aupLG8Z66yt6bQBsPjf228km+0l6N56TqfaB+AL9MLhaJYJhJAAO8GgABF4BA0PgwCAiGBaCB4ABhcBQAA8ABUAHzVbC4cjwDIACgAlGQybZcGdKjIyKhliEQCkaTclABpaB5aAzJJBABm0DJVh5fPIAuUIr0TQK0AAPii0RisTi8YTiRByaKrBS9IY0NbXGhurhwkopbL5VYlN1oTFTXr0blDcR0EKSic-QbscRyRSGf7MZH4EhskxcgU9HDEWRUXHA7j8US4tGWfL5jdIXMgrQAFbVOkZZgI+DMgDch1w5eg1HgnFQMEUGfgADpORdW3YZUF0AyO12e9A3bOjBAmaWvgA3MDoJSLtAAOTAXb0O9QZMbGt4qCYAHkZTL0Uw9PjyH5FMfW192yEeHgI0RE0JuyMaocwTJBBwgShaByWML2vW970feByBXAB6FDAkoOZNXyaAFiCEAkGaH8A1AztALQaAGWxGZ9AARwyNA4UofAgnhdRoBlVAgmoaB4AADwPeF8SZNsbnwOUGQHBdyJPRtoAAQnkRQACJsOUlchQ-edq23GT9y7F9wxIv9UEHbNf2IWMLP-GSjxk09ESZd8P0ieAQHRcUJOPBykSU-QbWMDToDQ3CwHIJB8WgeFcmofB+DXJEB2gQjbzQJDWCSOwvkrKtdJ7fT4EM+FN3RABJcgmCs4ziCQACexXAIwpSAIyRdeBpTlBVnK+Vz3KRcTKO8uS-M0FNmnUIKQoWMKIqRaL8Fi+LErklKZTSiqBSym4cryowCsMkC-1qmTen8chmpgVrXU6qxupub0ersXkmEoVByG0qtnOhb0Qq0v6vlgEQAEFkSkcQrwhyGr2RABNaAAFpkrRYBcnhfgQnnOUAANDpqrGjlTHD6BAIIMiwX7-v+mQZDJMkABlKIyJZeWganqnuFZwL-PRaYZxQObQQdHBXKIO1xxNqnUdp2gsWX6MYpJmNY9QYi-OZiumWYyAmTW5kUczqsFg34z-EkdZmJgY3FpA9HN2YRPJ9D+MRYAmAlrGNYt-GcvgV2CcoV3XqRMAZTd9BUEochyCIrHjcDeAscd8ZJgtpPcAAKlw5YKPhqlngYCnKY-TOtCRXOOnaNOi+L5hWFwcvZYsKvM5+FJy-+Kvq+gTP6gRqlwahiHYaAA)