# Use variable holding type as a generic type parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

Is there any way to use `a` variable as a generics parameter?

```
static triple<T>(x): T[] {
    return [x, x, x]
}


class A {}
let a = A; // variable type is `typeof A`

const instance = new A();

triple<A>(instance); // works
triple<a>(instance); // ERROR: 'a' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104545/recursive-generic-function-with-type-passed-as-a-parameter)?  If so we should probably close one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass to generic real value but you can use `typeof a` in this case